# How to know whether particular extension was promoted to a core profile, was made a core extension from the start or removed as a legacy extension?

Tags: opengl

I'm using core forward-compatible profile of OpenGL 3.3. Supported extensions list such extensions as GL_ARB_MULTITEXTURE and similar (which is marked as removed in OpenGL 3.1 in OpenGL wiki), but why is this extension is reported as available by my driver? Also, GL_NV_primitive restart is reported as available, but it can't work with server side OpenGL 3+. So can the driver report arbitrary extensions as supported even when they shouldn't be available or usable?

My conclusion is that I can't rely on the driver providing correct information about extensions. Futhermore, standard says that the driver in not obliged to report core extensions too, but it might.

Now, if I have an extension reported as GL_foo_bar for GL version a.b using the core profile, how do I know if is it not a legacy extension for that particular setup, how do I know if that particular extension is not already part of the a.b core.

This pseudo code is not portable between different OpenGL: versions: if(GL_foo_bar == TRUE) will work in OpengGL 2 and might not work on OpenGL3+ if GL_foo_bar is part of the core and not reported as available by the driver. I can't find a foolproof way to know whether that particular extension is really not supported or simply not reported, so it seems I need a separate rendering paths if I do not want multiple if's between each GL function call.

Off topic: why does glGetString(Gl_EXTENSIONS) work with my core profile? I think that it should not.

Comment: "*core forward-compatible profile*" Please stop doing that. Just use the core profile. [Forward-compatibility is pointless with profiles.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts#Forward_compatibility) "*why does glGetString(Gl_EXTENSIONS) work with my core profile?*" Because your driver is buggy.

Comment: @NicolBolas what's wrong with using with forward compatible? If something would be deprecated someday again, I want to stop my program working immediately, so I could fix my code to be future proof.

Comment: Because there's no point in not using something that's supported by OpenGL. Wide lines have been deprecated since GL 3.0, but they remain part of the core OpenGL profile despite being marked deprecated. Indeed, the deprecated list in core OpenGL has a few items, most of which have been marked deprecated for years. Yet they're still there. The ARB is clearly not willing to pull the trigger on getting rid of them (especially considering how "successful" the core/compatibility distinction has been thus far). So there's no point in pretending that they're fated to disappear.

Comment: Also, if the OpenGL Wiki says that ARB_multitexture was "removed" from core OpenGL, then please show where so that I can *remove that* from the Wiki.

Comment: @NicolBolas As far as I'm not concerned about internal politics of ARB and I want to be sure that I use only valid stuff and would not depend on what they will or will not decide to do in the next ten years. GL specification mess is hard to understand even right now, I don't want to be hunting for what stuff was deprecated in what version anytime soon. Wiki link: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_ARB_multitexture If you fix the wiki, then a lot of functions have they core since versions wrong, like: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glActiveTexture It's core since 1.3 (GL_ARB_MULTITEXTURE).

Comment: "*I don't want to be hunting for what stuff was deprecated in what version anytime soon.*" Then don't. "Deprecated" *does not* mean "removed" or "unavailable". Furthermore, if you ask for OpenGL, core profile, version 3.3, then the implementation is required to give you core profile 3.3, or some higher version of OpenGL that is *backwards compatible* with it. So either you'll get something that implements what you asked for, or you won't get a valid implementation at all. So again, forward-compatibility is *useless* to you.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, let's say I would use wide lines now without regarding to the fact they are deprecated. And in like 5 years somebody would remove them from the core implementation. It wouldn't be possible to simply compile my program and work with any future core implementations (if I won't switch to compatibility profile) just because of that. I will need to remember to remove wide lines first. (And I would need to remember that these are wide lines that are causing problems). My program is asking for the latest core profile available currently.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28193/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-user206334)

Comment: You should have the rep to go into chat, but in case you don't, here's the short version. It's not possible to guarantee that a program will work with *any* future version of OpenGL, because in the future new things could be removed that have not *yet* been deprecated. The only protection you have against this is asking for a specific version of OpenGL, which forces the implementation to support *all* the features of that version, or else you don't get a context at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions are not "removed". Your implementation supports whatever extension it wants, whether it makes sense against the current version of OpenGL or not.

> My conclusion is that I can't rely on the driver providing correct information about extensions. Futhermore, standard says that the driver in not obliged to report core extensions too, but it might.

This conclusion seems to be coming at the problem from the wrong direction. Versions and extension matter to you in exactly one respect: what do *you* want to support?

If you aren't going to use NV_primitive_restart, then whether or not a core OpenGL implementation mentions it in the extension string is entirely irrelevant to you. You shouldn't care if the extension string mentions ARB_multitexture or not unless you're expecting to do something differently based on whether or not it is present.

If you're supporting GL 2.1, then you need to figure out which extensions on top of that you wish to support, either conditionally or as required functionality. Then you write your code against those extensions and that version number.

> if GL_foo_bar is part of the core

Unless GL_foo_bar is a [core OpenGL extension](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Extension#Core_Extensions), it is *never* "part of the core". The functionality behind an extension can be promoted to core, but the extension and the core functionality remain *different*. That's why they have suffixes.

The buffer object functionality from ARB_vertex_buffer_object was promoted to core OpenGL in 1.5. But the behavior of the functions exposed by ARB_vertex_buffer_object is *not the same* as the behavior of the similar functions exposed by core OpenGL. GL 3.1 allows this to work: `glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffer);`. Calling that with `glBindBufferARB` *might* work (and odds are, it probably will), but there's no *guarantee* that it will work, regardless of OpenGL version number or the presence of some combination of extensions.

This is why core extensions exist. So that you can call the same functions and get the same behavior. The same function will be available if the extension is present or the OpenGL version is >= the appropriate number. So the general pseudo-code is this: `if(gl::exts::ARB_uniform_buffer_object || gl::VersionGEQ(3, 1))`.

Comment: I created OpenGL extension availability list: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At5QLa2ZAYZBdHFLbEtvOHF5S1NobWJFbmpDUHZSWWc&usp=sharing It allows one to check when were particular extensions promoted, in what versions they might be usable, etc... I hope most of the info is correct. One can edit simply by having a link.

Comment: @user206334: I would consider it wrong to say that ARB_geometry_shader4 was "promoted" in any real way. The core 3.2 functionality of GS's is so radically different in form from the extension (even if it's the same functionality) that there's really no relation between them.

Comment: So you can fix, remove. I just gathered all the info which was scattered in the appendices. I found it strange too, but it was listed as promoted so I got it included. Let me find exact wording: G.3.3.40 Geometry Shaders "The name string for geometry shaders is GL_ARB_geometry_shader4. It
was promoted to a core feature in OpenGL 3.2." I'm simply not qualified enough to question validity of this item.

Comment: There are more extensions which have no effect for OpenGL API (and were explicitly marked that they only affect GLSL), but were listed as promoted into the GL core. I suppose that means that shading language used with that core supports these extensions by default.